# Execute javascript template to produce HTML by ruby server?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I have JST template (tpl javascript to create HTML). It's normaly used by the client (in JS). But I want my sever ruby be abble to produce himself the views.
I don't want remake the JST template, converted to ruby because:

1) twice the same code in 2 languages => more maintain/debug
2) twice more work, for same result is waste my time

You will tell me: "just make a ruby template", but I don't want to. I want client auto-generate his HTML. But, for referencement, I need sometimes the ruby server rendering directly HTML and not just JSON, so my question is:

how can I execute JS template with ruby server? Others solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to tackle this problem:-

**1)Use Node Server -Common JS Templates in client and server- HTML rendering as a service from JS template**

In your server you can call node service with template name and parameters like to render datepicker you can call http:\localhost/datepicker/date/month/year, since your templates are in JS , Node server will also be able to render those.See dust.js ,it works almost on similar lines.

**2)Just maintain 1 server side templates with variable name prefilled**

Lets say you template is

```
<div>My name is ${name}</div>
```

With this template you can render on server side by providing correct name as "abc" or "def", etc.

When ever client needs template you can  send the same template with name parameter as "$$name", and in client js you can replace $$name to the correct name.

Thus maintaining same template on server as well as client.

**3)Use some solution similar to google closure**

If you were asking the same thing in JSP this was straight forward solution, but you can look for similar thing in ruby world.

Comment: I think about nodeJS server, but the goal is not send requests/not to make the server work when the client have download the JS assets with all templates. If all clients (and server ruby) have to request server nodeJS, it's not good for performance. So I have to duplicate code: one in JS package for client, and an other one in server nodeJS... boring, no?

Comment: for second solution: it will works for basic template, but for exemple: ```<% for index, value of @ : %>
    <option value="<%=value.id%>"><%=value.name%></option>
  <% end %>``` It's more complicate, because have JS instructions... (and more than JS, here it's coffee script!)

Comment: if you are ready to use NodeJS or rhino then you can look into dustjs. basic idea is to use NodeJS just for serverside rendering, while client side it will work because already in JS.
You need not be using dustjs , but you can build on the same idea for your templates.

Comment: It's posible with nodeJS server to read file in app/assets/javascript/templates/ of my rails app? If we can load template like that, I can use same code for both !

Comment: Yes that's the idea, use same JS code by either creating simlink or  by directly reading it in file system.

I think you got the essence.